# Replacing fs.readFile with fs.createReadStream in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, stream

I have code for reading an image from directory and sending it to index.html.

I am trying to replace fs.readFile with fs.createReadStream but i have no idea how to implement this as i can not find a good example.

Here is what i got (index.js)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var fs = require('fs');

http.listen(3000, function () {
     console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
     fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/images/image.png', function (err, buf){
        socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
     });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>

<script>
    var socket = io();
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    socket.on("image", function (info) {
        if (info.image) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + info.buffer;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
    });
</script>
</body >
</html >
```

Comment: You can try using [socket.io-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream).

Comment: I don't want to use additional modules.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The below approach only uses core modules and reads the chunks from the `stream.Readable` instance returned from `fs.createReadStream()` and returns those chunks back as a `Buffer`. This isn't that great of an approach if you're not going to stream the chunks back. You're going to hold the file within a `Buffer` which resides in memory, so its only a good solution for reasonably sized files.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  fileToBuffer(__dirname + '/public/images/image.png', (err, imageBuffer) => {
    if (err) { 
      socket.emit('error', err)
    } else {
      socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: imageBuffer.toString('base64') }); 
    }
  });
});

const fileToBuffer = (filename, cb) => {
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    let chunks = [];

    // Handle any errors while reading
    readStream.on('error', err => {
        // handle error

        // File could not be read
        return cb(err);
    });

    // Listen for data
    readStream.on('data', chunk => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    // File is done being read
    readStream.on('close', () => {
        // Create a buffer of the image from the stream
        return cb(null, Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });
}
```

#### HTTP Response Stream Example

Its almost always a better idea to use `HTTP` for streaming data since its built into the protocol and you'd never need to load the data into memory all at once since you can `pipe()` the file stream directly to the response.

This is a very basic example without the bells and whistles and just is to demonstrate how to `pipe()` a `stream.Readable` to a `http.ServerResponse`. the example uses Express but it works the exact same way using `http` or `https` from the Node.js Core API.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const server = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

server.get ('/image', (req, res) => {
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/images/image.png')

    // When the stream is done being read, end the response
    readStream.on('close', () => {
        res.end()
    })

    // Stream chunks to response
    readStream.pipe(res)
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question and providing an answer to my question.

Comment: @AESTHETICS updated my answer with HTTP Streaming example.