# Read large files in chunk using createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```
var data = '';
var startOffSet = 0;
var endOffSet = 0;

do {
    if (fileSizeInBytes >= 64000 && fileSizeInBytes - endOffSet >= 64000) {
        endOffSet += 64000;
    } else {
        endOffSet += fileSizeInBytes - endOffSet - 1;
        inProcess = false;
    }
    startOffSet += 64000;

    var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('fileName', { start: startOffSet, end: endOffSet });

    readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
} while (fileSizeInBytes > endOffSet + 2);
```

The problem with is this method is that it does not set the correct start and end offset. It starts the 'data' event after adding the entire start/end offset. Although, when debugging, it works in the intended way.

Comment: It's because `readableStream.on` is asynchronous, it doesn't do its work immediately. The loops probably goes on and on before the first `readableStream.on` call finishes its work.

Comment: Is there anyway fix it? Any alternative? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very familiar with nodejs, let alone `createReadStream`. I'll see if I could figure out a way, but really don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Why don't you just read it using `fs.readFile`?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43261014/6647153 helpful?

Comment: I want data in chunks. createReadStream makes it easier to manipulate start/end offset. Link did not help either.

Comment: did you solved it ?